# check if 2 IDs are the same in Django template engine

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure why Django is not comparing these value correctly, here's what I have:

```
    {% for comments in comments %}
        {% for this_a in avatar %}

                {% if comments.author_id == this_a.uid_id %}
                  {{ comments.author_id }} EQUALS {{this_a.uid_id}} <br>
                {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

For some reason the != is not comparing the IDs and I'm getting this output:

```
2 EQUALS 2 
2 EQUALS 3 
3 EQUALS 2 
3 EQUALS 3
```

Why am I getting "2 EQUALS 3" and "3 EQUALS 2"?

I've also tried "ifequal" and I'm getting the same result, how can I resolve this?

Comment: "Why am I getting 2 EQUALS 2", because it does, and that's what you're testing against with '=='?  the 3 EQUALS 2 is a little more interesting.

Comment: my mistake, before I posted this I also tried != and was getting 2 NOT EQUAL 2

Comment: I think what you are comparing is not what you think you are comparing. Can you post what `comments.author_id` and `this_a.uid_id` are? From your model or view?

Comment: We usually see `comment.author.pk` if you want to get the primary key. `author_id` is something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the confusion is coming from the {% for comments in comments %} -- both are plural, so this is the equivalent of saying for x in x.  Try changing removing the s in the first one, so it reads:

{% for comment in comments %}

and then all the variables in your loops to comment.author_id.  I'd have to do some testing, but the template parser may be confused as to which "comments" you should be using at each moment.